# What does 2500 pixels on the long dimension mean?

Tags: resize, pixel-size

I have a rather silly and very simple question. In all photography competitions, they mention that the pictures should be sized to `x` number of pixels on the long dimension. What does that exactly mean? For example, in one of the photography competitions, they ask for `2500px` on the long dimension.

Does that mean:

If I have a picture which has dimensions `4800 x 3200` `(w x h)`, the longest dimension is `4800` which is the `width`. And they want the `width` to be `2500` instead of `4800`.

Similarly, If I have a picture which has dimensions `4000 x 6000` `(w x h)`, the longest dimension is `6000` which is the `height`. And they want the `height` to be `2500` instead of `6000`.

I have never made such conversions before. I know, the answer is pretty straight forward. I just wanted to confirm before I submit my work and don't make any stupid mistakes.

Thank you.

Comment: Exactly, 2500 pixels in the longest dimension.

Comment: Why the `code formatting`?

Comment: What else could it mean? 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly. And Lightroom and some image editors will allow you to export an image with a desired value for the "long edge" (rather than for desired width or height). It keeps your resize operations much more consistent, assuming you don't do a lot of cropping.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, just make sure neither the width nor the height exceed 2500px for your picture.